# fb.event.subscribe and facebook comment box

Tags: facebook

## Context:

I have a facebook app that is using the facebook comments box.

In this app a user can create an item for sale.

The item for sale is available at `facebook_url_for_the_app/item/itemnumber`.

When the user that created the item for sale (or any other user) visualizes the page for the created item, the facebook comments box is available.

## Desired function:

Currently, if any user writes a comment the user that created it will only know about it if he visits the page.

## My Idea to solve the problem:

I have looked into `FB.Event.subscribe('comments.create')` but there isn't a field to identify a user other than the admin of the application.

## Question:

How can I tell my app to create a subscribe to any comments created at the item's page, `facebook_url_for_the_app/item/itemnumber`.

Comment: You can subscribe to the comment creation and then get the user get the user in the callback function.

Answer (score 2):

Joka,

If you subscribe to comment.create event

```
<script>
  FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(resp) {
    Log.info('Comment was added', resp);
    // add code here to id the user e.g FB.api('/me', function(response) {})
  });
</script>
```

You can then add code to do something with the uid returned by the FB.api call

Answer (score 0):

Joka: I guess this link will help you out in some way. Here u can subscribe for the event and use it accordingly to notify the user.

[click here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5374396/a-simple-question-about-facebook-comments-plugin/5743095#5743095) to view the page

Answer (score 0):

You may want to also make them a moderator of the comment box by adding the metatag

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="{THEIR_FACEBOOK_USER_ID}"/>
```

to the head.